# How to Add custom field to aspnetcore Identity aspnetUserClaim table

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, customization

I'm making an app with ASP.NET Core and Identity, and I need to add a custom field to the `aspnetuseclaim` table. I know some how I must inherit the `IdentityUseClaim<>` and do the customization but doing it and make the identity context to use this class is not that easy. Can any one help me with a sample?

Comment: Claims are key-value pairs and not really meant to be modified. Are you sure you want to modify Claims, not something else? what is the actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a specific case with identity server .I want assign the claims to users on certain client.I need to add client if to table

Comment: Fair enough. I guess this should be part of the question - to draw answers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to modify the `AspNetUserClaims` table also.  I needed to add some auditing fields such as Created, CreatedBy, Modified and ModifiedBy.  It was not that obvious at first to me, but here is what I did:

I created a new class (`AuditableUserClaim`) that inherited from the existing `IdentityUserClaim<string>` class and added my custom properties to it.

Then I had to call a different base constructor from my `ApplicationDbContext` class.  The signature looked like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string, 
            AuditableUserClaim, IdentityUserRole<string>, IdentityUserLogin<string>, 
            IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
```

I hope this helps someone, I knew it had to be possible :).